# How to perform word-count distributions graphs?

Tags: python, graph, distribution, word-count

I have a column of text like this in a dataset:

```
Text
This is a long string of words
words have many types
each type represents one thing
thing are different
where are these words
```

How to draw word counts distribution graphs for all words and order by descending order? Like 'are' has 2 counts,'thing' has 2 counts...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, please show some code that you tried and explain what problems you encountered. If not, then where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collections.Counter` to count the occurences of a word. Simple example is given below.

```
from collections import Counter
sent = "xyz employees went for a strike. There are many employees in xyz company."
dt = Counter(sent.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting words in a string can be a pretty involved process, depending on what you are looking for. For instance, do you want `wasn't` and `was not` to match? Do you care about capitalization? Etc..

I will have to make some assumptions about what you are trying to achieve for this answer:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from collections import Counter


def word_histogram(words, ignore_capitalization=False):
    words = words.replace("'", "")
    if ignore_capitalization:
        return dict(Counter(word_tokenize(words.lower())))
    return dict(Counter(word_tokenize(words)))


print(word_histogram("Text\nThis is a long string of words\nwords have many types\neach type represents one thing\nthing are different\nwhere are these words", True))
```

Output:

```
{'text': 1, 'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'long': 1, 'string': 1, 'of': 1, 'words': 3, 'have': 1, 'many': 1, 'types': 1, 'each': 1, 'type': 1, 'represents': 1, 'one': 1, 'thing': 2, 'are': 2, 'different': 1, 'where': 1, 'these': 1}
```